# I changed fonts in my very basic website written in HTML5. Will the fonts be available on other pcs which dont have the font?

Tags: html

I changed the font of a paragraph using the span tag. The font is available on my computer but I don't know if it will be available on the PCs which don't have the font. If it doesn't, is there a way to make it available for them without them having to download it?

Comment: Go research: “web fonts”

Comment: https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)

Answer (score 0):

No they won't. The font have to be on the website server. You can you the google font to do want you want and make them available everywhere. https://www.google.com/fonts

And use the `font-face` CSS rule :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont; /* give a name to your font */
    src: url(myFileFontFile); /* select the font file */
}

.my-class {
    font-family: myFirstFont; /* apply the font to your div or span or whatever */
}
```

Comment: So will the font-face rule allow me to use fonts that aren't meant to be used as web fonts?

Comment: No, it will work with web fonts and fonts which are stored on the server

Comment: Is there any reason to use fallback `sans-serif` or `sans`, when you import a font?

Comment: Yes when the first fonts are not found (was it ironic? )

Comment: No, it's a genuine question, because I was assuming the font would always be loaded from the server.

Comment: Yes sorry : on the client.

Comment: So if i store the fonts on my website server, will they work then?

Comment: No, it will work with web fonts and fonts which are stored on the ***client*** (i made a mistake in my first comment)